# How to activate MK360 logitech numeric keyboard (right side)?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I just bought this keyboard. Everything is working fine, except the numeric keyboard numbers at the side doesn't work.

I googled, but not a clear response was out there. Any idea how to fix this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds a lot like numlock isn't engaged

Comment: No the numlock doesn't activate the numbers. Any way how to fix this @Journeyman Geek

Comment: Just realized that the numlock worked on Ubuntu, but not my windows 10 laptop. Any reason ?

Comment: That indicates the hardware is fine. And it should be hardware based ... so that's odd.

Comment: Based on your experience, what do you suggest me to do or search for to fix this problem on windows 10 ?

Comment: Well, I just ruled out the obvious. Try booting into safe mode next. If that works, you've narrowed it down to a keyboard specific driver. After that, not too sure